# I stumbled upon a strange issue where a Exchange Shared mailbox continued moving emails from Inbox to Recoverable Items folder

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

we have shared mailbox with full access for many people and someone deleted all items in this shared.

I run the command

Search-MailboxAuditLog -identity BelovedCustomersMailbox -LogonTypes Delegate,Owner -ShowDetails

That gives me no result related to the Soft Delete. No error.

It's Exchange Server 2013. On shared mailbox Audit logging has been enabled.

I checked everywhere including:

- mailbox settings in Exchange Server admin portal
- Exchange  transport rules
- Exchange  Shared Mailbox Inbox Rules - ---   Get-InboxRule -IncludeHidden
- No any retention policy
- get-calendarprocessing ---->>> automateprocessing : AutoUpdate

Still with no evidence.

---

Are there any logs about MoveToDeletedItems?   Yes There are 3 records.

Do you added the -Mailbox sharedmailbox when using Get-Inboxrule?

yes

what if you recover these items to the inbox, will them be deleted after a while?
No ,  after recovering items , no any action

Answer (score 1):

Are there any logs about MoveToDeletedItems? Please also use `Get-Mailbox SharedMailbox | FL *Audit*` to check what actions could be recorded.

Do you added the -Mailbox sharedmailbox when using Get-Inboxrule?

And what if you recover these items to the inbox, will them be deleted after a while?

You could try repairing the mailbox with [New-MailboxRepairRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailboxrepairrequest?view=exchange-ps).

Sorry that I was meant to add a comment, but it said that the point should be 50 to do so.

Comment: thanks btw I have updated my question

Comment: Thanks for the update. 
What's the result of Get-Mailbox SharedMailbox | FL *Audit* ? Will the SoftDelete enabled for both owner and delegate?

Comment: AuditDelegate    : {Move, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete}
AuditOwner       : {Move, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete}

Comment: Please also add admin to check if someone delete these items with EMS:

Search-MailboxAuditLog -identity BelovedCustomersMailbox -LogonTypes Delegate,Owner,admin -ShowDetails

I tried using EMS to delete these items with Search-Mailbox -DeleteContent, and the LogonType is admin.